# How to get list of words for each topic in pyLDAvis

Tags: nlp, lda

I am new to using pyLDAvis. I have been looking through the documentation but cannot seem to find a way to get the set of words for each topic of my model. I have 20 topics and I would like to get the top 20 or so words for each topic. Does anyone have a way of getting this data?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include code and trace-back. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pyldavis.prepare()` method produces a `PreparedData` object with attributes like `.topic_info` that returns a DataFrame with the words, `logprob` etc (see [docs](https://pyldavis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/API.html#pyLDAvis.PreparedData))

```
from pyLDAvis.gensim import prepare
vis = prepare(lda_model, corpus, dictionary, mds='tsne')
vis.topic_info

     Category         Freq       Term        Total  loglift  logprob
term                                                                
2299  Default 2,068,609.00      order 2,068,609.00    30.00    30.00
1037  Default   816,951.00      drink   816,951.00    29.00    29.00
2778  Default   565,075.00     review   565,075.00    28.00    28.00
```